# Restful Webservice Java, server side

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I'm trying to develop a small server which would include one restful webservice.

I'd like to use JAX-RS for the webservice part, but every example I'm seeing is using a tomcat server, and I can't use any 'application' server (meaning I can create a server in my code, but can't run it from the outside).

Well anyway I was wondering if anyone had any sample to show, and any advice on which light library I could use to run such a simple server into my code (can't use any gpl /lgpl etc licence, so no jersey for example).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to embed Tomcat in your application, see here for an example: http://java.dzone.com/articles/embedded-tomcat-minimal

Another popular choice for an embedded servlet container is [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/), they have a tutorial [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty).

#### Edit

The examples provided with Jersey can also be helpful, here's one for running using the Grizzly HTTP library: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/helloworld/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/helloworld/App.java

You can even use the HTTP server that's bundled with the JDK (probably not the way to go for a real application): https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/helloworld-pure-jax-rs/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/helloworld/jaxrs/App.java

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with Jetty & Restlet since Grizzly & Jersery are under gpl license.

Comment: Both Grizzly and Jersey are also licensed under the CDDL- not quite as permissive as Apache, but far from the GPL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out http://www.sparkjava.com/?
It's very light-weight and concise.

Answer (score 0):

Building a server into code is nothing. See ["Embedding Jetty"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty), for one. There are plenty of other options with varying degrees of difficulty and capabilities, like the [Simple Framework](http://www.simpleframework.org/), [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Embedded.html), [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/docbkx2.0/html/quickstart.html), [Netty](https://netty.io/), and [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/), to name a few. Then, if you're not stuck with Java, the language, there's [Ratpack](https://github.com/tlberglund/ratpack-template) for a lightweight REST server. Otherwise, running something like Jersey in an embedded server is quite simple. I do it every day in tests.